# mn is is even iff m is even or n is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

The problem states:

> Let $mn$ be integers. Show that $mn$ is even if and only if $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

They are asking to prove an iff statement. So it can be said that $P→Q$ and $Q→P$. I can prove that $¬P→¬Q$ and $¬Q→¬P$ as far is I understood.

I tried it like this:

$¬P→¬Q$: $mn$ is odd if $m$ and $n$ are odd. An odd integer can be represented as $2x + 1$, so we can rewrite $mn$ as $(2x + 1)(2y + 1) =  2(2xy + x + y) + 1$ which is odd.

$¬Q→¬P$: if $m$ and $n$ are odd, then $mn$ is odd. How to write this then? Isn't that essentially the same as the previous? Or did I misunderstand how to prove iff in this case.

Comment: For the second part, prove $P\to Q$ directly.

Comment: Why *if and only if* m *OR* n are even . What if both are even?

Comment: "if $m$ and $n$ are odd, then $mn$ is odd". This is: $m=2k+1$ and $n=2l+1$, then $mn=(2k+1)(2l+1)=2(2kl+k+l)+1$ and it is correct. In this way we have proved: "if (not-($m$ is even) and not-($n$ is even)), then not-($mn$ is even)" i.e. $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$ which is equiv to $P \to Q$.

Comment: For $Q \to P$ assume that one of $m$ and $n$ is even; let it $m=2k$. Then $mn=(2k)n=2(kn)$ and thus we have that also $mn$ is even. In this way we have $Q \to P$.

Comment: *Conclusion*: having proved that $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$, we may conclude with: $P \leftrightarrow Q$.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA that explanation cleared it up, I got it now. Is that the usual pattern for proofing `iff`?

Comment: Yes; $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$ imply $P \leftrightarrow Q$. Of course, it is not always necessary, in order to prove $P \to Q$, to prove $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$; a direct proof will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to prove a biconditional 'P if and only if Q' you want to prove both 'If P then Q' and 'If Q then P'.

And yes, in order to show a conditional 'If P then Q', you can also show its contrapositive 'If not Q then not P'.

However, just because you show the one conditional 'If P then Q' through its contrapositive, does not mean that you have to show the other conditional 'If Q then P' by its contrapositive as well. Hence, there are 4 ways to prove a biconditional 'P if and only if Q':

1. You show 'If P then Q' and 'If Q then P'
2. You show 'If P then Q' and 'If not P then not Q'
3. You show 'If not Q then not P' and 'If Q then P'
4. You show 'If not Q then not P' and 'If not P then not Q'

(and by the way, a common mistake I see is that someone proves: 'If P then Q' and 'If not Q then not P' ... that does *not* work, since they are each other's contrapositive, so you really only show one direction twice!)

Now, which of these 4 methods do you use. Well, it makes sense to pick the easiest one.

So, for the 'If $mn$ is even, then $m$ is even or $n$ is even', I think you did indeed pick the easiest one by considering its contrapositive 'If $m$ and $n$ are odd, then $mn$ is odd'

However, for the other direction 'If $m$ or $n$ is even, then $mn$ is even', the direct proof is probably easier than the contrapositive: all you need to do is consider the 2 cases:

Case 1. $m$ is even. Then $m=2k$ for some integer $k$, and hence $mn=2kn$ is even.

Case 2. $n$ is even. Then $n=2k$ for some integer $k$, and hence $mn=2km$ is even.

Since either $m$ or $n$ is even, and since in both acses we get that $mn$ is even, we have shown that $mn$ is definitely even (proof by cases)

Comment: Oh that's a good summary, thank you!

Comment: @Max You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the statements identically. The contrapositive statements would be that if $mn$ is odd, both $m$ and $n$ are odd, and if $m$ and $n$ are odd, then so is $mn$.

What if and only if means here is this: if you already know that $m$ or $n$ is even, and you don't yet know about $mn$, you can infer that $mn$ is even. So the proof of that is to say that if, say, $m = 2k$, then $mn = 2kn = 2(kn)$, so is even.

The other direction is that if $m$ and $n$ are both odd, we can automatically infer that $mn$ is odd. This is the proof you gave.